# How to set alias permanently using command?

Tags: unix, alias

I don't have access to home directory. So I can't access .bashrc or .profile file.
So the only option (I guess) is using the command for setting alias.

Is there any way to add alias permanently using any command (Without using .bashrc or .profile) ?

Comment: Does not belong here, but try `alias --help`, IIRC there is just one option.Not so hard. Try that next time first, always.

Comment: how come you don't have access to the home directory?  I mean whoever the user you log in as, there should be a home directory

Comment: You should contact your system administrator and ask the to fix your account instead. Or, if that no home / no access to .bashrc is by design, then you need to ask them to relax that policy.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have any permanent local storage, then you just can't make any permanent settings change. If you do have some permanent local storage that isn't your home directory (which would be pretty strange), you can run this every time you log in:

```
export HOME=/path/to/permanent/storage
. ~/.profile
```

You could put your settings in a file available somewhere on the web, at an URL you can remember easily. Then, assuming your home directory is writable (but, I suppose, erased when you log out or something like that), you can download that file and run it:

```
wget http://www.example.com/~suresh/.profile
. ./.profile
```

In addition to shell settings, this `.profile` might contain an archive that it unpacks when you run it, so that you get a `.bashrc`, a `.emacs`, a `.vimrc`, a `.Xresources`, and whatever else you like. The `shar` commands from [sharutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/sharutils/) creates an archive which is embedded in a shell script which unpacks the archive when you run it, relying only on ubiquitous utilities.