# How to set a command without defining path everytime?

Tags: jre, jdk

I have a command which is:

```
./keytool
```

But I always have to go to this folder to use it:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.65-2.b17.el7_1.x86_64/jre/bin
```

How can I just use the following command in my whole environment instead of defining the path every time?

```
keytool
```

How do I have to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set alias permanently using command?](http://superuser.com/questions/205714/how-to-set-alias-permanently-using-command)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to create a symbolic link to any folder currently in your PATH-variable, in this example we use /usr/bin/.

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.65-2.b17.el7_1.x86_64/jre/bin/keytool /usr/bin/keytool
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following line at the end of the `.bashrc` (or `.profile`) file that is in your home directory :

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.65-2.b17.el7_1.x86_64/jre/bin
```

This is however a very fragile approach, since it will not work as expected as soon as you update your java installation. If you want to do it more properly, I suggest a couple of ways:

look in the `/etc/alternatives` folder, see if there's a link named `java`pointing to the current java home (could be pointing to another link). If it's there, change the export line with

```
export PATH=$PATH:/etc/alternatives/java
```

or (depending on your system), you could have a link in `/usr/lib/jvm`, something like `/usr/lib/jvm/java` pointing to the most recent version of the jvm you have installed. If it's there, you can use this one, so the export line is

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/jvm/java
```

Apart from that, if you want it to be system-wide (instead of limiting the path extension to your user), you should add the line to `/etc/bashrc` (or `/etc/bash-bashrc` if it's there).

As a final note, this will only work in newly-created shells, not the ones you already have, unless you issue the command

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

(or the file you've modified, if it's not `.bashrc`) in those shells.